# Mongo C# driver - Building filter dynamically with nesting

Tags: c#, mongodb

Assume something like a nested expression

> where a = 1 AND ( b = 4 OR b = 5 )

How to use multiple Builders objects and build a complete filter out of such an expression?

Comment: Is this a C# related problem? Do you want to build an expression dynamically?

Comment: I am sorry to keep the question incomplete. Yes, it's using C# driver 2.0 Builder classes. Yes, I want to build the expression into FilterDefinition dynamically.

Answer (score 142, accepted):

`Builders` is really flexible class, it also has overridden operators "**&** = AND" and "**|** = OR"

Your example will be

```
var filter = Builders<User>.Filter.Eq(x => x.A, "1");
filter &= (Builders<User>.Filter.Eq(x => x.B, "4") | Builders<User>.Filter.Eq(x => x.B, "5"));
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll try to use this approach. The difficult part will be parsing the string based expression and building the nested FilterDefinition. Because when I parse the string into filter objects, I will go left to right and and will have to start with outer most builder and then navigate to child builders...may be I need some tree data structure

Comment: best answer.. congrats!!

Comment: you'll definitely need to build a tree to do this correctly. Sounds like a fun project

Comment: The other thing I'd consider here is that you don't need multiple builder objects. You can use the same builder for multiple filters.

Comment: You can use: filter &= (Builders<User>.Filter.Eq(x => x.B, "4")

Comment: The accepted answer should be fixed to reflect @nikolai.serdiuk comment.

Answer (score 23):

if you want conditionally add more filters use this method:

```
var builder = Builders<Student>.Filter;
var filter = builder.Empty;

if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(firstName))
{
   var firstNameFilter = builder.Eq(x => x.FirstName, firstName);
   filter &= firstNameFilter;
}

if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(lastName))
{
   var lastNameFilter = builder.Eq(x => x.LastName, lastName);
   filter &= lastNameFilter;
}

if (minAge != null && maxAge != null)
{
   var ageFilter = builder.And(builder.Gt(x => x.Age, minAge),
      builder.Lt(x => x.Age, maxAge));
   filter &= ageFilter;
}

var result = await _plpResultCollection.Find(filter).ToListAsync();
```

Comment: thats what I came here for :)

Comment: This doesn't work if you use or (|=) expression, it will return all collections because of builder.empty

Answer (score 17):

You can use very simply like this way.....

```
var filter = Builders<Rental>.Filter.Where(s => s._id== id && s.Price==1500);
```

Comment: Although this doesn't answer the OPs question, it did help me on "my mission".