# Select WHERE {some regex} AND someProp='someValue' in mongodb

Tags: c#, regex, date

In my mongoDB database I want to perform query that matches to some regex AND to another condition

roughly I'm trying to perform the query:

`SELECT * COUNT('Start Job Date') From myTable WHERE 'Start Job Date' match {some regex} AND Result=Drop`

> i.e I want the count number of all droped files that matchs the date regex.

Each document looks like:

```
{
    "_id": "5d709ed019038b60fc944274",
    "Result": "Drop",
    "File Size (Bytes)": "915",
    "Start Job Date": "20190905083550"
}
```

For now I have:

```
IMongoDatabase db = dbClient.GetDatabase("myDB");
var collection = db.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("myTable");
FilterDefinition<BsonDocument> filter= Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Regex("Start Job Date", new BsonRegularExpression(expression, "i"));
int  droped= collection.Find(new BsonDocument("Result", "Drop"),filter).ToList().Count;
```

The error is in this line:

```
int  droped= collection.Find(new BsonDocument("Result", "Drop"),filter).ToList().Count;
```

because `Find` method doesn't recieved both arguments together.

Comment: Do not compare the hours, minutes seconds.  Only look at first 8 characters of the date.

Comment: @jdweng Of course, but it's not answering the question  :\

Comment: I have found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32253436/11253551)