# Bool logic for filter creation in a for loop using C# MongoDB drivers

Tags: c#, mongodb

So, i am trying implement the following mongoDB filter in C# :

```
find({ "$or" : [
 {"$and":[{ "isPublic" : false}, {"_id" : ObjectId("60c0bfc23b3ffd14f2675104")}]},
 {"$and":[{ "isPublic" : false}, {"_id" : ObjectId("60c0bfe43b3ffd14f2675105")}]},
 {"$and":[{ "isPublic" : false}, {"_id" : ObjectId("60c0c1863b3ffd14f2675106")}]}] 
});
```

The above filter needs to be create in a for loop, because the number of the nested "ands" can vary.

Using the accepted answer of https://stackoverflow.com/a/32253436/16185277, i tried the following:

```
FilterDefinition<documents.poses> idFilter;
FilterDefinition<documents.poses> isPublicFilter = Builders<documents.poses>.Filter.Eq(x => x.isPublic, false);
posesFilter = Builders<documents.poses>.Filter.Empty;
foreach (ObjectId _id in DBManager.loggedInUser.poses){
    idFilter = Builders<documents.poses>.Filter.Eq(x => x._id, _id);
    posesFilter |= isPublicFilter & idFilter;
}
```

The filter that is created by this chunk of code is:

```
find({ "$or" : [{ },
 { "isPublic" : false, "_id" : ObjectId("60c0bfc23b3ffd14f2675104") },
 { "isPublic" : false, "_id" : ObjectId("60c0bfe43b3ffd14f2675105") },
 { "isPublic" : false, "_id" : ObjectId("60c0c1863b3ffd14f2675106") }] })
```

I also tried the following, which created the exact same filter as the above.

```
FilterDefinition<documents.poses> idPublicFilter;
FilterDefinition<documents.poses> isPublicFilter = Builders<documents.poses>.Filter.Eq(x => x.isPublic, false);
posesFilter = Builders<documents.poses>.Filter.Empty;
foreach (ObjectId _id in DBManager.loggedInUser.poses){
    idPublicFilter = Builders<documents.poses>.Filter.Where(x => x._id == _id && x.isPublic == false);
     posesFilter = Builders<documents.poses>.Filter.Or(idPublicFilter, posesFilter);
}
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: have you considered using an in clause? ie find({ { "isPublic" : false}, {"_id" : "$in":[ ObjectId("60c0bfc23b3ffd14f2675104"),ObjectId("60c0bfe43b3ffd14f2675105"),ObjectId("60c0c1863b3ffd14f2675106")] });

Comment: Hey @MikeT, thanks for the answer! Your approach worked and is way cleaner than mine. Do you want to post it as an answer, so i can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using an in clause which would look something like

```
FilterDefinitionBuilder<Poses> filter = new();


var ids = poses.Select(p => p.ID);

var f = filter.And(
    filter.Eq(f => f.isPublic, false),
    filter.In(f => f.ID, ids)
);
```

failing that would be building a filter enumerable and then combining in an or clause

```
List<FilterDefinition<Poses>> filters = new();
foreach (var item in poses)
{
    filters.Add(filter.And(
        filter.Eq(f => f.isPublic, false),
        filter.Eq(f => f.ID, item.ID)
    ));

}
var f = filter.Or(filters.ToArray());
```